# what does handleSegMousedown: function(seg, ev) mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain to me what this part of the code does? 
I don't understand what is `handleSegMousedown: function(seg, ev)`

```
handleSegMousedown: function(seg, ev) {

    var isResizing = this.startSegResize(seg, ev, {
        distance: 5
    })

    if (!isResizing && this.view.isEventDraggable(seg.event)) {
        this.buildSegDragListener(seg)
            .startInteraction(ev, {
                distance: 5
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I fixed it for you this time, but when you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Always worth taking the time to make your post clear and easy to ready.

Comment: Hi, thank you. It is first time when I ask a question :D

Answer (score 0):

What you've quoted would only exist within an object initializer, like this:

```
var obj = {
    handleSegMousedown: function(seg, ev) {

        var isResizing = this.startSegResize(seg, ev, {
            distance: 5
        })

        if (!isResizing && this.view.isEventDraggable(seg.event)) {
            this.buildSegDragListener(seg)
                .startInteraction(ev, {
                    distance: 5
                });
        }
    }
};
```

That's a *property initializer* for the property named `handleSegMousedown`, where the value is a function accepting two formal parameters, `seg` and `ev`.

The object will end up having a property with that function as its value, which presumably it uses as some kind of event handler. When the event occurs, the handler will get called with two arguments (presumably), one for `seg` and another for `ev`. (This isn't a normal DOM event handler; if it were, `ev` would be the first parameter.)